# How can I write an object method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object method that doesn't work and it's giving me this error:

```
buyBike: (money) => {
    ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

This is my code:

```
let money = 500;

let bike = {
    cost: 300
    buyBike: (money) => {
        if (money >= this.cost) {
            money -= this.cost;
        } else {
            console.log("You don't have enough money to buy this bike.");
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is the right way to write an object method in JavaScript?

Comment: Your code needs a comma after `300`. Also you'll need to use a traditional function in order for the references to `this` to work properly.

Comment: Ok, but what is a traditional function? Do I need to enter the ```function``` keyword?

Comment: Yes, `buyBike: function(money) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I've put together the working example so you can see it in code.

```
let money = 500;

let bike = {
    cost: 300,
    buyBike: function(money) {
        if (money >= this.cost) {
            money -= this.cost;
            console.log("Sold!");
        } else {
            console.log("You don't have enough money to buy this bike.");
        }
    }
}

bike.buyBike(money);
```